# Image not showing in header when added in div

Tags: php, html, css

I have Below code in my header.html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="logo">
     <a href="http://example.com/themes/default/images/logo.png"></a>    
   </div>
</div>
```

But it's not showing my png image in header, Is the way adding image path in div is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<img src="http://example.com/themes/default/images/logo.png">
```

That is how you use an image. You are placing a link to the image.
Also, you are not seeing anything because your `<a></a>` tags are empty. If you write something between them, you can click on it, to see the image you linked.

Answer (score 1):

Add Image inside the `img` tag not in `a` tag

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/themes/default/images/logo.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do is this way. **img** tag is used to display image.

Good practice is to link the logo to the home page of the website.

```
<div class="col-md-3"><div class="logo"><a href="Link to your home page"><img src="http://example.com/themes/default/images/logo.png" alt="Site Name or Logo"/></a></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

put link or path  in img tag  source(src) not anchor tag.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="logo">
     <a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/themes/default/images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
   </div>
</div>
```